# Return from different function

Tags: php

Just wondering, is it possible to refactor this code so that calling the function `$this->getApiAuthenticatedUser()` will directly return `$this->userTokenResponse` to the caller of `getUserData()`.

```
public function getUserData(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * No user token is pass or invalid token
     */
    if( !$this->getApiAuthenticatedUser() )
    {
        return $this->userTokenResponse;
    }
    // Do more stuff
}
```

More or less become like this

```
public function getUserData(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * No user token is pass or invalid token
     */
    $this->checkUserToken();
    // Do more stuff
}

public function checkUserToken()
{
    /*
     * No user token is pass or invalid token
     */
    if( !$this->getApiAuthenticatedUser() )
    {
        return $this->userTokenResponse; // Need to return 2 level of function
    }
}
```

Comment: Which code is the actual one? :|

Comment: What is the purpose of returning the token when something is invalid? Sounds more like you are looking for exceptions...!?

Comment: Top one is the actual code, Bottom is somehow what I want to refactor to @Goikiu

Comment: When the token is invalid, I return the token absent error code. If auth pass, I process the token to get the user data @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to return "2 level of function", each function decides what is returned and not returning just means no value is given back, you still get back to the parent function afterwards (if you would still catch the "non" return value it is probably `NULL`). Using `if` is the right way to do that. So either the condition is TRUE then return, else do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're really more looking for exceptions:

```
public function getUserData(Request $request) {
    $this->assertUserTokenIsValid();

    // Do more stuff
}

public function assertUserTokenIsValid() {
    if (!$this->getApiAuthenticatedUser()) {
        throw new InvalidUserTokenException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't quite understand what you're after, but may be this?

```
public function getUserData(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * No user token is pass or invalid token
    */
    return $this->checkUserToken();
    // Do more stuff
}

public function checkUserToken()
{
    /*
     * No user token is pass or invalid token
     */
    if( !$this->getApiAuthenticatedUser() )
    {
        return $this->userTokenResponse; // Need to return 2 level of function
    }
}
```